# Кончилась ли for break'ом

Tags: c#, циклы

Можно ли как-нибудь после выполнения for, проверить, закончился ли цикл сам или его прервал break?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ввести переменную и перед break ее взводить.

Comment: Как же не хватает break n, который даже в php есть, а  c# нету

Comment: Так там так и сделано,  только прозрачно для программиста

Comment: @vitidev, в c# для этого goto есть

Comment: Среди поограммистов ходят упорные слухи, что использовать goto - это моветон.

Comment: @Smithson, про `break` тоже такое слышал, а еще что `for` вообще не нужен, если есть `while` ))

Comment: @Grundy goto не заменяет он break n.

Comment: @Smithson: Это спагетти-код — моветон. А goto вполне себе ничего, только пользоваться надо с умом и при необходимости.

Comment: @Smithson goto, break, continue - по сути одно и тоже, безусловный переход. Безусловные переходы в высокоуровневом коде, как правило приводят к ухудшению читаемости кода и невозможности читать код сверху вниз. Есть много мнений на этот счет, как и про сколько return должно быть в функции, но суть сводится к одному, если в безусловном переходе есть реальная необходимость, ничего плохого в нем нет, если просто лень разобраться и написать правильное условие для цикла - то таки да, моветон.